# If I have worked at a company previously should I include that on my CV?

Tags: resume

I did 6 months internship at a company and I was wondering if I should include this on my CV when applying to them.

I think its fairly obvious that I should but should I be careful about my wording of my time with them? Should I say more or less about that time?

Comment: You should perhaps say what you did. Why less or more?

Comment: what concern do you have about mentioning or describing the internship? Was it a bad experience? Did you do a poor job?

Comment: I mean, they know what i did so is there any point in me telling them in detail. No they have been asking me to send in a CV so presumably they think i did a good job.

Comment: Unless you worked for Murder Inc. or the Sinaloa cartel is no no reason not to include it.

Comment: If you're *reapplying* to Murder Inc. or the Sinaloa cartel, there's no reason not to mention that you worked there before (well, depending on the circumstances of your departure).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definitely include it. For many larger companies, a manager in one department would never know that you previously worked elsewhere in the company.

Regarding the description, you should be as concise in describing your responsibilities and accomplishments in that group as you would for any other company on your resume.

Comment: Its actually a fairly small company, they asked me t send in a CV when i was applying for jobs.

Comment: Consider also mentioning by name the person you worked with if they are still at the company.